# Saving Dash layout to html

Tags: python, html, plotly, plotly-dash

I plotted a bunch of things in a dash layout. I want to save them to an html file so I can look at them later. when I reopen the saved html file, I first see everything correctly. However, within <1s, the page goes blank and I get an error: “Error loading layout”. (see gif below)

How can this be fixed?

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: is there anything in your console? (in chrome press f12, click console and refresh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is not fully working:

You have to save your Webpage complete.
To prevent the javascript creating any errors
i have removed the ***bundle(2).js*** file.

This file contains the function `dash_renderer` which tries to interact with the server and creates issues.

```
<footer>
<script id="_dash-config" type="application/json">{"url_base_pathname": "/", "requests_pathname_prefix": "/"}</script>
<script src="./Dash_files/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Dash_files/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Dash_files/bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./Dash_files/plotly-1.38.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Dash_files/bundle(1).js"></script>
<!-- <script src="./Dash_files/bundle(2).js"> --></script>
</footer>
```

The result is the same page as you can see for ~1s.

Big disadvantage: **The interactivity from plotly is lost.**

Comment: Nils, this is great! At least it gives me the ability to save for later. It would be great if Dash automatically did this if it doesnt detect the server

Comment: I will take a look into it and maybe create a commit on github 

Comment: UPDATE: this answer no longer works with Dash 2.3.1 @Nils do you know an updated method?

Answer (score 1):

A Dash app `layout` is serialized as JSON and served to the front-end by the Dash server (an extension of a Flask server).
All Dash components included in your layout are bundled as JS/CSS files. These bundles are also served by the Dash server to the front-end.

Without the server, there is no one to send JSON, JS, CSS bundles to the front-end, so nothing will be rendered.

I'm not sure why you can see your app for a brief moment. My guess is that Dash saves a PNG image of your app every time you run it. Think of it like a splash screen you see before the real, reactive app shows up.

Have a look at this [high-level overview](https://dash.plot.ly/plugins) on how Dash works under the hood.

Comment: Thanks @jackdbd. My background is scientific computing not web dev so I apologize for my ignorance. Is there anyway I can save a dash layout. I know I can save multiple plotly plots in a jupyter notebook to html, so I figure this should be possible in Dash.

Comment: No need to apologize, I also feel dumb all the time. Anyway, unless your layout is composed by dash html components exclusively, I don't think that you can save it in any way. Long story short, for a dash core component HTML is not enough. See also here: https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/44#issuecomment-311154651

Comment: are you aware of a way to save dash layouts to html that would work?